# wifi not working properly on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: networking

**MY LAPTOP:** HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC. 
**OPERATING SYSTEM:** *dual boot* Ubuntu 23.04 64-bit *and* Windows 10 64-bit. 
**KERNEL VERSION:** Linux 6.2.0-31-generic. 
**WIFI ADAPTER:** Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter.

---

**The Problem:** when i am using Ubuntu 23.04 and connect to a WiFi router the internet connection is unstable, slow, and frequently disconnects. When I connect to the internet using my phone through USB tethering I have no issues and the internet is fine. 
On the same laptop I have Windows 10. When I boot into Windows 10 and connect to the internet router through WiFi I have no issues and the internet is fine. 
 I installed Debian 12 and Linux mint 21 and still having the same problem with internet connection when using WiFi.

---

*can you help me please.*

Comment: This driver https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver says that it covers up to 22.04 but it may work with 23.04.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Actually WiFi has disappeared completely from my laptop after installing this driver.

Comment: Try running the script in https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/231142 and it should help find the correct info for the Wireless card.